# Error passing generic values to method using implicit parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I have implemented the following code in Scala

```
trait Implicit[A,B] { def method1(a:A, b:B) : Boolean }

object Implicit {
    implicit object IntImplicit extends Implicit[Int,Int] {
        override def method1(a: Int, b: Int): Boolean = a == b
    }
}

object Main
{
    def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit =
    {
        println(test(4,3))
    }

    def test[A,B](a:A, b:B)(implicit i: Implicit[A,B]) : Boolean =
        i.method1(a,b)
}
```

and it actually works fine. But if I define the following function

```
def jump[A,B](a:A, b:B) : Boolean = test(a,b)
```

into the Main object, it tells me that there is not "enough arguments for method test". I suppose that it's because it is not able to define the actual implicit value at compile time. Is it true or the problem is something else? If yes, how can I solve this problem?

Obviously this is just a simplification of the problem in order to replicate a condition where I have to call a method that declares an implicit parameter not previously knowing the actual types.

Comment: @DanielCazares, if you want the bounty to be assigned to some answer you have to do it manually. There is no way it could be assigned automatically.

Answer (score 6):

The error you *should* be getting is:

```
scala> def jump[A, B](a: A, b: B) : Boolean = test(a, b)
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter i: Implicit[A,B]
       def jump[A, B](a: A, b: B) : Boolean = test(a, b)
                                               ^
```

In order to call `test` with a generic `A` and `B`, the compiler needs to be able to find an implicit instance of `Implicit[A, B]`. Since `A` and `B` can be *anything*, the only way the compiler can find such an implicit for `test` is if you require the same implicit for `jump`:

```
def jump[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit i: Implicit[A, B]) : Boolean = test(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to be able to define `def jump` it needs to be defined as

`def jump[A,B](a:A, b:B)(implicit i: Implicit[A,B]): Boolean = test(a,b)`

as you suspected. The implicit value counts as one of the parameters that need to be passed in.

Wherever this is called from needs to have an implicitly defined value of type `Implicit[A,B]` in scope.

Comment: ok, in my concrete problem jump can not require de implicit value because it's overriding a more general function. In this case it seems that the only solution will be a patter matching inside test instead of the implicit declaration